# create Json Object from String Android

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I tried to get an answer from server and conver it to `JSONObject`.
At Now I have this code

```
private JSONObject sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data, String actionname)

{

    // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
    try

    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new      
        HttpPost(actionname);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //   Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = convertStreamToString(is);

     //   JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray (result);
       // int eventID = jArr.getJSONObject(0).getInt("eventID");

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
        return jObject;

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
    }

    return null;  

}
```

in `result` string variable I have this

> {"status":{"code":404,"text":"Not Found"},"content":"User
>   authentication failure"}

But on the string of code `JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);` - It go to the  return `null`;  =(( I tried to create `JSONArray` but it return me an extention that I can create `JSONARRAY` from `JSONObject`.

Comment: you must have error above line JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); jsut print the  result in log and check..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, but I don't understand why it so. May be I am not so good in OOP. So I create JSONObject jObject as a property of class JSONHandler, that have sendData method. And it became work. I will be happy if somebode explain me why it so.

Answer (score 1):

From `result` you can create `JSONArray` as follows:

```
JSONArray finalResult = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(result));
```

Once you have `JSONArray`, you can loop through to get the details, something like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < finalResult.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject message = finalResult.getJSONObject(i);
    String content= message.getString("content");
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Value {"content":" ","status":{"text":"Not Found","code":404}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray - took this